# Bidirectional A* (A-Star) Not Returning the Shortest Path

Tags: javascript, algorithm, path-finding, a-star, bidirectional

For some reason, my implementation of bidirectional A* isn't returning the shortest path in very specific initializations of the graph.

I'm running two A* searches, one from the source to the destination, and one from the destination to the source. From what I've read, when the closed sets for both of these searches intersect, then we've connected the shortest paths from both searches and have found the shortest path.

The problem is, in very specific situations, the closed sets for both searches are intersecting before the searches can actually discover the nodes which should be included in their respective shortest paths. This means A* doesn't get to explore enough nodes to find the shortest path.

Is this intersection condition the right way to go about things, or is there a different condition I should be using to figure out when to stop both searches?

You can run my code here: https://jasperhuangg.github.io/pathfinding-visualizer.

The cases where this problem occurs are certain (not all) situations when both walls and weights have been placed on the grid.

Here is the code if it helps, sorry if it is very messy!:

```
async function bidirectionalAStar(graph, startNode, finishNode) {
  recolorGrid();
  searching = true;

  const infinity = Number.MAX_VALUE;
  var openSource = [];
  var openDest = [];
  var closedSource = [];
  var closedDest = [];

  var numSteps = -3; // -2 for both start and finish nodes + -1 for overlapping connecting node

  $("#steps-taken").html("Cells Examined: " + numSteps);

  const startX = startNode.x;
  const startY = startNode.y;

  const finishX = finishNode.x;
  const finishY = finishNode.y;

  var bidirectionalAStarGraph = shallowCopyGraph(graph, []);

  // initialize all nodes to dist infinity from the startNode
  for (let i = 0; i < bidirectionalAStarGraph.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < bidirectionalAStarGraph[i].length; j++) {
      bidirectionalAStarGraph[i][j].fSrc = infinity;
      bidirectionalAStarGraph[i][j].gSrc = infinity;
      bidirectionalAStarGraph[i][j].hSrc = infinity;
      bidirectionalAStarGraph[i][j].fDest = infinity;
      bidirectionalAStarGraph[i][j].gDest = infinity;
      bidirectionalAStarGraph[i][j].hDest = infinity;
      bidirectionalAStarGraph[i][j].setSource = "neither";
      bidirectionalAStarGraph[i][j].setDest = "neither";
    }
  }

  // initialize start/finish node distance from start/finish to 0
  bidirectionalAStarGraph[startX][startY].fSrc = 0;
  bidirectionalAStarGraph[startX][startY].gSrc = 0;
  bidirectionalAStarGraph[startX][startY].hSrc = 0;
  bidirectionalAStarGraph[startX][startY].setSource = "open";
  openSource.push(bidirectionalAStarGraph[startX][startY]);

  bidirectionalAStarGraph[finishX][finishY].fDest = 0;
  bidirectionalAStarGraph[finishX][finishY].gDest = 0;
  bidirectionalAStarGraph[finishX][finishY].hDest = 0;
  bidirectionalAStarGraph[finishX][finishY].setDest = "open";
  openDest.push(bidirectionalAStarGraph[finishX][finishY]);

  var lastNodeSource;
  var lastNodeDest;

  while (openSource.length > 0 && openDest.length > 0) {
    openSource.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.fSrc !== b.fSrc) return a.fSrc - b.fSrc;
      else return a.hSrc - b.hSrc;
    });
    openDest.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.fDest !== b.fDest) return a.fDest - b.fDest;
      else return a.hDest - b.hDest;
    });

    var currNodeSource = openSource.shift();
    var currNodeDest = openDest.shift();

    $(".currentNodeGray").removeClass("currentNodeGray");
    $(".currentNodeSunset").removeClass("currentNodeSunset");
    $(".currentNodeOcean").removeClass("currentNodeOcean");
    $(".currentNodeChaos").removeClass("currentNodeChaos");
    $(".currentNodeGreen").removeClass("currentNodeGreen");
    $(".currentNodeCottonCandy").removeClass("currentNodeCottonCandy");

    if (checkIntersection(closedSource, closedDest)) {
      break; // the paths have reached each other
    }
    numSteps += 2;

    $("#steps-taken").html("Cells Examined: " + numSteps);

    currNodeSource.setSource = "closed";
    currNodeDest.setDest = "closed";
    closedSource.push(currNodeSource);
    closedDest.push(currNodeDest);

    colorNode(currNodeSource, "currentNode");
    colorNode(currNodeDest, "currentNode");
    if (lastNodeSource !== undefined && currentSpeed !== "instantaneous")
      colorNode(lastNodeSource, "visited");
    if (lastNodeDest !== undefined && currentSpeed !== "instantaneous")
      colorNode(lastNodeDest, "visited");

    if (currentSpeed === "fast") await sleep(20);
    else if (currentSpeed === "medium") await sleep(180);
    else if (currentSpeed === "slow") await sleep(500);

    var validNeighborsSource = [];
    var validNeighborsDest = [];
    var left = currNodeSource.x - 1;
    var right = currNodeSource.x + 1;
    var up = currNodeSource.y - 1;
    var down = currNodeSource.y + 1;

    // consider all of the current node's (from source) valid neighbors
    if (left >= 0 && !bidirectionalAStarGraph[left][currNodeSource.y].blocked) {
      validNeighborsSource.push(
        bidirectionalAStarGraph[left][currNodeSource.y]
      );
    }
    if (
      right < grid_width &&
      !bidirectionalAStarGraph[right][currNodeSource.y].blocked
    ) {
      validNeighborsSource.push(
        bidirectionalAStarGraph[right][currNodeSource.y]
      );
    }
    if (up >= 0 && !bidirectionalAStarGraph[currNodeSource.x][up].blocked) {
      validNeighborsSource.push(bidirectionalAStarGraph[currNodeSource.x][up]);
    }
    if (
      down < grid_height &&
      !bidirectionalAStarGraph[currNodeSource.x][down].blocked
    ) {
      validNeighborsSource.push(
        bidirectionalAStarGraph[currNodeSource.x][down]
      );
    }

    left = currNodeDest.x - 1;
    right = currNodeDest.x + 1;
    up = currNodeDest.y - 1;
    down = currNodeDest.y + 1;

    // consider all of the current node's (from dest) valid neighbors
    if (left >= 0 && !bidirectionalAStarGraph[left][currNodeDest.y].blocked) {
      validNeighborsDest.push(bidirectionalAStarGraph[left][currNodeDest.y]);
    }
    if (
      right < grid_width &&
      !bidirectionalAStarGraph[right][currNodeDest.y].blocked
    ) {
      validNeighborsDest.push(bidirectionalAStarGraph[right][currNodeDest.y]);
    }
    if (up >= 0 && !bidirectionalAStarGraph[currNodeDest.x][up].blocked) {
      validNeighborsDest.push(bidirectionalAStarGraph[currNodeDest.x][up]);
    }
    if (
      down < grid_height &&
      !bidirectionalAStarGraph[currNodeDest.x][down].blocked
    ) {
      validNeighborsDest.push(bidirectionalAStarGraph[currNodeDest.x][down]);
    }

    // UPDATE NEIGHBORS FROM SOURCE
    for (let i = 0; i < validNeighborsSource.length; i++) {
      let neighbor = validNeighborsSource[i];

      if (neighbor.setSource === "closed") continue;

      let cost = 0;
      if (currNodeSource.weighted === true || neighbor.weighted === true)
        cost = currNodeSource.gSrc + 10;
      else cost = currNodeSource.gSrc + 1;

      if (neighbor.setSource === "open" && cost < neighbor.gSrc) {
        neighbor.setSource = "neither";
        neighbor.gSrc = cost;
        neighbor.fSrc = neighbor.gSrc + neighbor.hSrc;
        openSource.remove(neighbor);
      }
      if (neighbor.setSource === "neither") {
        openSource.push(neighbor);
        neighbor.setSource = "open";
        neighbor.gSrc = cost;
        neighbor.hSrc = calculateHeuristic(neighbor, finishNode);
        neighbor.fSrc = neighbor.gSrc + neighbor.hSrc;
        neighbor.predecessorSource = currNodeSource;
      }
    }
    lastNodeSource = currNodeSource;

    // UPDATE NEIGHBORS FROM DEST
    for (let i = 0; i < validNeighborsDest.length; i++) {
      let neighbor = validNeighborsDest[i];

      if (neighbor.setDest === "closed") continue;

      let cost = 0;
      if (currNodeDest.weighted === true || neighbor.weighted === true)
        cost = currNodeDest.gDest + 10;
      else cost = currNodeDest.gDest + 1;

      if (neighbor.setDest === "open" && cost < neighbor.gDest) {
        neighbor.setDest = "neither";
        neighbor.gDest = cost;
        neighbor.fDest = neighbor.gDest + neighbor.hDest;
        openDest.remove(neighbor);
      }
      if (neighbor.setDest === "neither") {
        openDest.push(neighbor);
        neighbor.setDest = "open";
        neighbor.gDest = cost;
        neighbor.hDest = calculateHeuristic(neighbor, startNode);
        neighbor.fDest = neighbor.gDest + neighbor.hDest;
        neighbor.predecessorDest = currNodeDest;
      }
    }
    lastNodeDest = currNodeDest;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any code I can't identify any specific bugs in your algorithm but the thing about Bidirectional A* is that it is only as good as your A*.

A* is flexible in that it is capable of acting just like a dumb breadth first search and just like a dumb depth first search - usually it's somewhere in the middle, and that "middle" is defined by the quality of your heuristic.

Adding a second A* on the other side is a good way to "speed up" an A* heuristic that leans towards breadth, but, it won't "fix" a heuristic that leans towards depth.

If you want a guarantee that your Bidirectional A* search will always find the *shortest possible* path, then your heuristic needs to lean towards breadth.  (Usually this is done by estimating the heuristic - the imagined cost of a node to explore as the Manhattan distance to the target plus the distance traveled to that node.  Then sort the nodes and toss nodes more than 1.5x the lowest node -- 1.5 being a variable you can play with, too high and you'll do a traditional breadth first and too low and you might toss the actual lowest path, if it's a complicated one.)

Sorry for the vagueness, some code snippets might help give more direction!

Comment: I'm using the cost function that you specify: f = heuristic (Manhattan distance to finish) + g (distance to node). What I'm not doing is tossing out nodes in the closed sets; is this absolutely necessary or is it more just to save space? Also, can you confirm if finding the intersection of the closed sets is the right way to end the search?